# knockout mapping creates array of numbers not observables

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here is the data:

```
var data = {"netIncome":{
      "forecast":[1387,1861,2551,0]
    }
};
```

when I use "ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this)", "netIncome.forecast" is an array of numbers, not an array of observables. so of course when I change a value in the array, the change is not reflected in the model.

I would expect it to be the same as:

```
ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.netIncome.forecast,function(val){return ko.observable(val)}));
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yx4yb0y6/

Is there an option in the mapping plugin for this? my actual data contains over 100 similar objects so manually setting each one is not desirable!

Comment: from the knockout page: _Arrays are converted into observable arrays. If an update would change the number of items, it will perform the appropriate add/remove actions. It will also try to keep the order the same as the original JavaScript array._ This means that the values themselves are not observable, just the array itself. You'd have to manually map it as you were.

Comment: I just created a little hacky method to loop over the properties and look for arrays of numbers and convert the values to observables. See updated fiddle.

Comment: @dperry if the values in the arrays are objects then it will convert these to observables, it just doesn't convert values in arrays of primatives to observables.

Comment: what does, your update?

Comment: well actually `arrayMap` & `ko.mapping.fromJS` usage will be like this as given in fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/yx4yb0y6/7/ . In arrayMap you are returning a observable and expecting `.fromJS` to do the same . actually it wont work like that . refer docs for more info . cheers .